# How to handle "enter" button on a hardware keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm developing an android app for Honeywell EDA50K that has hardware keyboard as you can see on the picture

[image]

that what i would to do it's to manage it's "ENTER" hardware button and do some operation when it has been clicked.

so the question is how can i handle that button?

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this : `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`

Use this docs for help: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands#java

Comment: the point is that i've tryed it but it's working "bad" i mean when i open the activity and i press ENTER i've made the method to make a toast when it's pressed, and it's working only after 3rd time i'm pressing it and when it's focused in a edittext it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help (Keyboard Devices) :
https://source.android.com/devices/input/keyboard-devices